Parts in Revit - How to persist parameter data
Revit some times recreates the parts of elements, deleting some of the associated parameter data.
Is there any workflow / add-in that helps to persist data of Parts even in the case of automatic recreation of the Parts by Revit?
Thanks
António

I am not aware of any existing add-in for that specific task. Your safest bet would be to implement an add-in that stores all the required data in some location that is not touched by the conversion between part and non-part element.
